# Node.js & Express session problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a problem with sessions, where sometimes the session variable I *just* set
is undefined on the next page request.  I typically have to go through the flow
again in order to properly set the variables.

I can confirm that I'm not trying to set the session variables to undefined; they have a legit value.

In my app, users move from /twitter/connect/ to /twitter/callback/.  The former retreives some oauth data from twitter, the latter logs the user into twitter.

/twitter/connect/ is simple:

```
app.get('/twitter/connect/?', function(req, res){
    consumer().getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret, results){
        if (error){
            // error handling here
        } else {
            req.session.oauthRequestToken = oauthToken;
            req.session.oauthRequestTokenSecret = oauthTokenSecret;

            // if I console.log the two session variables above
            // they have the proper values.

            res.redirect("https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="+req.session.oauthRequestToken);      
        }
    });
});
```

After that, twitter sends them back to /twitter/callback/:

```
app.get('/twitter/callback/?', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session.oauthRequestToken);
    console.log(req.session.oauthRequestTokenSecret);

    // more often than not, the two variables above are
    // undefined.  but not always.  usually on the first
    // pass, never on the second.
});
```

I have no idea what's going on, I can confirm that the session variables are being set properly, they just aren't holding their value in between page requests, but only the first time.

This is how I'm creating my server:

```
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret:'yodawgyo' }));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('view options', {
        open: '{{',
        close: '}}'
    });
});
```

I just have a dev environment for now.  I have Node 0.5.0-pre installed, but saw this issue on 0.4.1 as well.  I'm using express 2.3.2.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue calling API's. I'm pretty sure the session info is getting lost on redirect. That is, if I refresh the page in my browser, I can see that the stuff I put in the session is still there. However, if I get to the *same page* via a redirect from some external site (e.g. oauth provider), the session is totally blank. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Update: looks like you get a different session id for the redirected request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just struggled with the same problem and got it resolved.
The simple answer is to call

```
 Session.save()
```

explicitly, if you cannot reply on express-session to call it for you at the end of the response.

[Reference](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsave)

Answer (score 19):

In Connect's session, any handler can set `req.session.anything` to any value, and Connect will store the value when your handler calls `end()`. This is dangerous if there are multiple requests in flight at the same time; when they finish, one session value will clobber the other. This is the consequence of having such a simple [session API](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html) (or see the [session source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js) directly), which has no support to atomically get-and-set session properties.

The workaround is to try to give the session middleware as few of the requests as necessary. Here are some tips:

1. Put your `express.static` handler above the session middleware.
2. If you can't move up some handlers that don't need the session, you can also configure the session middleware to ignore any paths that don't use `req.session` by saying `express.session.ignore.push('/individual/path')`.
3. If any handler doesn't write to the session (maybe it only reads from the session), set `req.session = null;` before calling `res.end();`. Then it won't be re-saved.

If only one request does a read-modify-write to the session at a time, clobbering will be less likely. I hope that in the future, Connect will have a more precise session middleware, but of course the API will be more complicated than what we have now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.  I moved the static handler above the session middleware, but was about all I could do.  All routes (only 4 of them) use either the session directly, or pass through middleware that does use the session.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I've opened up an issue on connect to track it: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/854

Comment: omg. your 1. solution fixed it. For some reason my session died between pages on POST. i had no idea why. but it just did. Once i moved the static above the session middleware it works!

Comment: what is static?  I don't have any such thing and i'm getting like 18 duplicate session rows in my database when i set a session variable once from a route handler.

Answer (score 4):

I filed an [issue against Express about github](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/702), but figured out what was wrong a few minutes later. Not sure if you're having the same problem, but for completeness:

In my case, I was testing by going to http://localhost:8003 but the OAuth provider was redirecting to [http://*hostname*:8003](http://%2ahostname%2a:8003). Same box/server/webpage, but different domain names means the browser sends different cookies and consequently, express gets different session ids and session data. As soon as I started testing at [http://*hostname*:8003](http://%2ahostname%2a:8003), everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

My code was similar to yours, structurally. In my case, however, my POST operation originated from the JQuery $.post function. I don't know if that makes an appreciable difference, *however*

What I ended up having to do was send a "junk" response at the end of the POST operation definition in my express routing routine, i.e.

`res.send("hoo hee ha ha unimportant junk data");`

By including this at the end I was able to trigger a success function (the callback for the AJAX post attempt). I inserted the redirect there, instead of placing it in the express routes.

Use with AJAX Post  `window.redirect();`

Do not use with AJAX Post: `$res.redirect("someurl");`

This is because browsers apparently will not redirect on AJAX response, so you have to use Javascript, as described here: [Express js - can't redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240447/express-js-cant-redirect)

Hope that helps someone, it fixed the problem for me, peace.

Comment: I love a bit o' the old _hoo hee ha ha_. Nothing quite like it.

Comment: Thank you Anwar! That saved me a giant headache. Worked a charm. Very strange that.