# Express js - can't redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to do the following:

**from client**

```
var req =  jQuery.post(
  "http://www.example.com:3000"+"/dologin", 
  {"username" : username, "password" : password}).error(function(){
    alert("an error occurred");
  });
```

**in express root**

```
app.post('/dologin',function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('http://bbc.co.uk');
});
```

**result passed back**

```
<p>Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to <a href="http://bbc.co.uk">http://bbc.co.uk</a></p>
```

Seems that if I do post from jquery the redirect will not work. Does anyone know a way to force it to redirect?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Browser does not redirect the window on redirect on ajax response. Redirect the browser with javascript.

In server send the new site as content, for example.

```
res.contentType('application/json');
var data = JSON.stringify('http://site.example.com/')
res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
res.end(data);
```

In client

```
var req =  jQuery.post(
   "http://www.mysite.com:3000"+"/dologin", 
    {"username" : username, "password" : password}, 'json').error(function(){
       alert("an error occurred");
    }).success(function(data) {
       window.location = data;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I ended up doing - thanks for the clarification. I was hoping they'd be overriding the request type on the server. `alessioalex suggested req.method = 'get'; but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Overriding request type does not matter, browser will not redirect the window location if it gets redirect response to Ajax request (e.g. $.post or $.get). btw. can you accept my answer if you think it's ok?

Answer (score 15):

I've actually encountered the same thing when developing an app. It seems Express doesn't redirect if the method is post.

Try:

```
app.post('/dologin',function(req, res) {
  req.method = 'get'; 
  res.redirect('http://bbc.co.uk'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately it didn't fix it. I think I'll change it to a get from jquery - essentially I am trying to set up a login form that (on fail sends a bit of json back describing the problem and on success redirects to another page in the site)

Comment: That's odd, I just made a test on a site with my solution above and it worked. Are you sure you're setting req.method to 'get' and not res.method.. ?

Comment: yep - using express 2.5    function(req, res) {
req.method = 'get';
res.redirect('http://bbc.co.uk');

Comment: In the expressjs guide (http://expressjs.com/guide.html#http-methods) the writer(tjholowaychuk) is using a redirect within a post route - app.post('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.user);
  res.redirect('back'); I guess that it is something to do with a callback being in the request. 
});

Comment: maybe you can put your code online somewhere so I can have a look (reduce your code a little though).

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated - It's all pretty much as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this when using OAuth2. I have an link to one of my pages and this in turn redirects to google.

To redirect to another location the following code does the actual redirect

```
app.get('/GoogleRequestAuthorization.html',function(req,res) {
.
.
.
.

res.writeHead(302, {location: url});
res.end();
```

});

url being the address you want to redirect to.

The full function is...

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a similar problem and solved it by checking the type of the  request. In my case I use JSON, but it works for other POST requests as well:

```
                var ajax = req.xhr;
                if(ajax) {
                    res.status(401).json({'msg':'redirect','location':'/login'});
                }
                else {
                    req.method = 'get';
                    res.status(401).redirect('/login');
                    //Or if you prefer plain text
                    //res.status(333).send("Redirect");
                }
```

This handles both Ajax POST and AJAX and standard GET requests.
On the client, in the Ajax respose callback:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: Msg,
        url: '/some/post',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).success(function(data, textStatus, req ) {
        if(data.msg==="redirect") window.location = data.location;
        else {...}
    }).error(function(data, textStatus, req) {
         if(req=="Unauthorized") {
            alert("Unauthorized!");
            window.location = "/login";
        } else if (data.responseJSON.msg==="redirect") window.location = data.responseJSON.location;
        else {
           //...
        }
    });
```

You can actually handle more statuses here, except for 302, which is automatically followed by JQuery and you get as response 200 from the page you wanted to redirect to. So I avoid sending the 302, sending 401 in my case, or any other status, for example 333, which will be handled as error.