# return response.sendRedirect in node.js is returning JSON and not rendering page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using response.redirect in my node.js application using express 4 and the redirect code is returning the 302 redirection response in JSON but not rendering the page

Here is my simple redirection code

```
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got signup request");
    return res.redirect('/login');
});
```

I tried res.render as well still no luck.

The funny part is, I do get a request on my login module, but how do I render the page?
The only option I can think of right now is to read the JSON response in the UI and then redirect it to Login page. 
But this will:

1. Hit two requests to the target page (right now it is login, but
   imagine if it is some other major page)
2. Expose the logic of redirection, which is a bad idea
3. Cannot transfer the data from one
   page to the other (I do not want to use localStorage or
   sessionStorage here)

Your kind help will be much appreciated
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: 1**
Login route

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got a login request");
    res.sendFile(GLOBAL.basePath+'/resources/login.html');
});
```

Comment: Render what page, you're redirecting to a different route?

Comment: @adeneo: Yes I am trying to redirect it to my login page.

Comment: Sounds strange, `res.redirect` shouldn't output anything, it should just redirect. You're sure you don't have output before that route

Comment: Yes, very strange. Especially seeing it working for other people. No, I do not have output before that route. Even if I have, would it affect res.redirect code? I hope it doesn't because redirection is happening through the response object

Comment: Well, I assume the redirect happens by setting headers, and if you have output before the `res.redirect` call you'd probably get a "headers already sent" problem.

Comment: @adeneo: I see. I do not have any output as of now. Do I need to manually set headers for the redirect?

Comment: What is in your `/login` route?  can you add it?

Comment: When the hit the url directly on the browser, the redirection works. But when I pass it from ajax it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Alright!
Express cannot do a redirection from an ajax call.
The redirection logic then has be taken care from the ajax success response.

[res.redirect from POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570301/res-redirect-from-post)

[Express js - can't redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240447/express-js-cant-redirect)

There are many other links to help on this issue