# node.js/everyauth: Maintaining session information with auth request

Tags: facebook, node.js, amazon-ec2, express, everyauth

Ok, so I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out! I'm trying to authenticate via Facebook.

I've got node (0.6.13) running express on an amazon ec2 server. I'm using everyauth for auth, and I have mongodb (mongodb native and connect-mongodb) for persistence. Here is how I instantiate mongo:

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoServer = new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true})
var mongoStore = new MongoStore({
    db: new mongo.Db('test', mongoServer, {})
  , reapInterval: 3000
});
```

I'm trying to authenticate through facebook using everyauth. So let's assume my app is running on port 3000, at http://ec2ip:3000/. My facebook app settings have the Website being redirected back to http://ec2ip:3000/.

Express is setup like so:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

 if(!req.session.auth || !req.session.auth.loggedIn)
 {
    console.log("Not authorized!");
    res.redirect('/auth/facebook/');    
 }
 else
 {
    console.log("Authorized!");    
    res.sendfile(__dirname +  '/www/index.html');
 }    
});
```

This *was* working locally, before I put it on the server. What will happen is that it will correctly authenticate with facebook, and redirect to my website, however req.session.auth will always be undefined, and it will redirect forever.  Even though I know it's successfully authenticated, it's just not passing the right session information.

It has something to do with setting up the redirect requests properly so session information is maintained, but I don't understand how it's working under the hood.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated. These are the related questions/problems I'm having, but I don't know how to apply it in my case: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/189 and [Node.js & Express session problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883821/node-js-express-session-problem)

Comment: did you manage to work it out Paul?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the value in "req.session". Then go get directly the value in object that you need.